# Conditional saveOrUpdate in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a mapped class that has a date property. I would like to saveOrUpdate objects of this class so that already existing is updated only if it is older than the stored one.

How would I do that (neatly and efficiently if possible)?

I have a lot of classes like this so I would hope to avoid writing tons of custom HQL for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try having a look at HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate from Spring . it has the same functionality as required.bieng open source you may see the code as well for implementation

Comment: Went some other way about it, but I think this looked promising.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is achieved in java but I am sure you can do something similar.

FYI, Classes below are NHibernate specific

You can extend the `DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener` class and override the `PerformSaveOrUpdate` method, in this method you can write custom code that will help you identify classes with Date properties in them (have an abstract class/interface that all this classes need to implement) and then set the value of this property and then call the base `SaveOrUpdate` method.

Then while building the `Configuration` you add this listener. Please refer to the Hibernate docs on how to do this.

Hope this helps you.